# How to uninstall Fedora OS from Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, windows, fedora

I have Ubuntu,Fedora and windows OS in my laptop.I want to remove Fedora OS only.How can i uninstall it ? Kindly suggest any good ideas.

Comment: You want to uninstall fedora from windows and yet you decide to post in Ask Ubuntu! If you [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/660217/edit) your question and make it 'uninstall from Ubuntu' you can save this question from being closed due to being off-topic! :)

Comment: thanks @Ron.do you have any idea how can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps to follow depend on if you wanted to install something over Fedora, or just reclaim the space so you can use it with Ubuntu/Windows (you didn't specify)....

"Gparted" is the name of the package you're looking for. It's probably already installed (http://gparted.sourceforge.net/ if not), so try just searching for it in the Dash.

You should be able to find the Fedora partition in gparted and either format it as a storage space(NTFS should be useable by both Ubuntu and Windows) , or delete it and extend whichever OS's partition to add it to the existing ones.

Notes:

1 - Be careful about highlighting the right drives/partitions before making changes.

2 - If you're going to extend the Ubuntu partition, you'll probably want to do that from the CD/USB you used to install.